# Erro: Mysql retorna o seguinte "Subquery return more than one row"

Tags: mysql, sql, moodle

Bom dia!
Criei esta query no mysql e ao adicionar a 1º subquery que chamei de "totalEscolas" recebo o seguinte erro: "Subquery return more than one row" sem esta subquery o código funciona blz.

Poderiam me ajudar? Obrigado!

```
  SELECT qs.slot as Questao, avg(fraction) * 10 as Media, qs.quizid as Quiz, qs.questionid as QuestaoID, q.name as Descritor, SUBSTRING(u.`department`,2,4) as Nivel, SUBSTRING(u.`department`,6,1) as Turma, q.category as cat, quiz.name as Simulado,

        (Select institution
    from fhrw_user listaEscolasU

    INNER JOIN fhrw_quiz_attempts listaEscolasQa ON listaEscolasQa.userid=listaEscolasU.id
    INNER JOIN fhrw_quiz listaEscolasQ ON listaEscolasQ.id=listaEscolasQa.quiz
    where listaEscolasQ.name=$P{simulado}
    and listaEscolasU.lastname=lastname
    and SUBSTRING(listaEscolasU.`department`,1,5) = $P{nivel}
    and SUBSTRING(listaEscolasU.`department`,6,1) = $P{turma}
    and listaEscolasQa.state="finished"
    ) as listaEscolas,

    (Select count(totalAlunosQa.id)
    from fhrw_quiz_attempts totalAlunosQa

    INNER JOIN fhrw_user totalAlunosu ON totalAlunosu.id=totalAlunosQa.userid
    INNER JOIN fhrw_quiz totalAlunosq ON totalAlunosq.id=totalAlunosQa.quiz
    where totalAlunosq.name=$P{simulado}
    and totalAlunosu.lastname=lastname
    and SUBSTRING(totalAlunosu.`department`,1,5) = $P{nivel}
    and SUBSTRING(totalAlunosu.`department`,6,1) = $P{turma}
    and totalAlunosQa.state="finished"
    ) as totalAlunos,

    (select avg(fraction) * 10 as mediaPT FROM fhrw_question_attempt_steps mediaqas 
    INNER JOIN fhrw_user mediau ON mediau.id=mediaqas.userid
    INNER JOIN fhrw_question_attempts mediaqa ON mediaqa.id=mediaqas.questionattemptid
    INNEr JOIN fhrw_question mediaq ON mediaq.id=mediaqa.questionid
    INNER JOIN fhrw_quiz_slots mediaqs ON mediaqs.questionid=mediaqa.questionid
    Inner Join fhrw_quiz mediaquiz ON mediaquiz.id=mediaqs.quizid
    inner Join fhrw_school mediaschool ON mediaschool.IdEscola=mediau.lastname
    where 
    SUBSTRING(mediau.`department`,1,5) = $P{nivel}
    and SUBSTRING(mediau.`department`,6,1) = $P{turma}  
    and mediaq.category = 7
    and mediaquiz.name=$P{simulado}
    and mediau.lastname=lastname
    and mediaqas.state!="todo"
    and mediaqas.state!="complete") as mediaGeralPT,

    (select avg(fraction) * 10 as mediaPT FROM fhrw_question_attempt_steps mediaqas 
    INNER JOIN fhrw_user mediau ON mediau.id=mediaqas.userid
    INNER JOIN fhrw_question_attempts mediaqa ON mediaqa.id=mediaqas.questionattemptid
    INNEr JOIN fhrw_question mediaq ON mediaq.id=mediaqa.questionid
    INNER JOIN fhrw_quiz_slots mediaqs ON mediaqs.questionid=mediaqa.questionid
    Inner Join fhrw_quiz mediaquiz ON mediaquiz.id=mediaqs.quizid
    inner Join fhrw_school mediaschool ON mediaschool.IdEscola=mediau.lastname
    where
    SUBSTRING(mediau.`department`,1,5) = $P{nivel} 
    and SUBSTRING(mediau.`department`,6,1) = $P{turma}  
    and mediaq.category = 8
    and mediaquiz.name=$P{simulado}
    and mediau.lastname=lastname
    and mediaqas.state!="todo"
    and mediaqas.state!="complete") as mediaGeralMT,

    (select avg(fraction) * 10 as mediaPT FROM fhrw_question_attempt_steps mediaqas 
    INNER JOIN fhrw_user mediau ON mediau.id=mediaqas.userid
    INNER JOIN fhrw_question_attempts mediaqa ON mediaqa.id=mediaqas.questionattemptid
    INNEr JOIN fhrw_question mediaq ON mediaq.id=mediaqa.questionid
    INNER JOIN fhrw_quiz_slots mediaqs ON mediaqs.questionid=mediaqa.questionid
    Inner Join fhrw_quiz mediaquiz ON mediaquiz.id=mediaqs.quizid
    inner Join fhrw_school mediaschool ON mediaschool.IdEscola=mediau.lastname
    where
    SUBSTRING(mediau.`department`,1,5) = $P{nivel}
    and SUBSTRING(mediau.`department`,6,1) = $P{turma}  
    and mediaquiz.name=$P{simulado}
    and mediau.lastname=lastname
    and mediaqas.state!="todo"
    and mediaqas.state!="complete") as mediaGeral





    FROM `fhrw_question_attempt_steps` qas

    INNER JOIN fhrw_question_attempts qa ON qa.id=qas.`questionattemptid`
    INNER JOIN fhrw_quiz_slots qs ON qs.questionid=qa.questionid
    INNER JOIN fhrw_user u ON u.id = qas.userid
    INNER JOIN fhrw_question q ON q.id=qa.questionid
    Inner Join fhrw_quiz quiz ON quiz.id=qs.quizid
    inner Join fhrw_school school ON school.IdEscola=u.lastname

    where 
    quiz.name=$P{simulado}
    and u.lastname=lastname
    and SUBSTRING(u.`department`,1,5) = $P{nivel}
    and SUBSTRING(u.`department`,6,1) = $P{turma}
    and state!="todo"
    and state!="complete"

    group by qa.questionid  
    ORDER BY `Questao` ASC
```

Comment: Seu sub-select está retornando mais de 1 registro, coloque no começo: `SELECT TOP 1 ......(resto da sql)`, ou ajuste seu sub-select para retornar apenas 1 valor.

Comment: @MaxRogério, obrigado por responder! 
A questão é que não gostaria de trazer apenas um registro, mas todos os registros da coluna "institution" da tabela "fhrw_user" isso é possível?
Nesta coluna são registradas as escolas que estão cadastradas, gostaria de trazer todas que realizaram determinado quiz

Comment: Então você terá que fazer o join com essa tabela (lembrando que pode-se repetir o join na tabela, é só mudar o alias), e depois fazer o tratamento da visão dos dados na sua aplicação ou o que estiver usando. Agora até onde eu sei(não sei muito), com subquery é necessário retorna somente 1 valor.

Comment: @MaxRogério eu achei que este join já fosse suficiente:
`INER JOIN fhrw_quiz_attempts totalEscolasQa ON totalEscolasQa.userid=totalEscolasU.id`

`INNER JOIN fhrw_quiz totalEscolasQ ON totalEscolasQ.id=totalEscolasQa.quiz`

Tenho que fazer ainda outro?

Comment: Como disse, se você quiser retornar mais de um valor "Instituiton", recomendo fazer JOIN ou repensar sua consulta...

Comment: @MaxRogério obrigado pela ajuda, mas não entendi este JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione um GROUP_CONTAT para retornar as escolas em apenas uma linha, a sua subquery está retornando mais de 1 linha.

```
(Select 
     GROUP_CONCAT(institution SEPARATOR ',')
from fhrw_user totalEscolasU
INNER JOIN fhrw_quiz_attempts totalEscolasQa ON 
totalEscolasQa.userid=totalEscolasU.id
INNER JOIN fhrw_quiz totalEscolasQ ON totalEscolasQ.id=totalEscolasQa.quiz
where totalEscolasQ.name=$P{simulado}
and totalEscolasU.lastname=lastname
and SUBSTRING(totalEscolasU.`department`,1,5) = $P{nivel}
and SUBSTRING(totalEscolasU.`department`,6,1) = $P{turma}
and totalEscolasQa.state="finished"
) as totalEscolas,
```

Comment: @arliondias
Acho que minha query acabou confusa, onde tem totalEscolas na verdade seria listaEscolas, pois não quero apenas contar mas listar as escolas. vou editar a pergunta

Comment: Você quer fazer todas as somas por escola, ou as somas em um geral e apenas listar as escolas? @MiguelSilva

Comment: As somas necessárias eu já consigo fazer, a query funciona, só não estou conseguindo listar as escolas, só falta mesmo listar as escolas

Comment: eu indico que retorne na mesma linha então, usando o GROUP_CONCAT, separando por ",". ai ficaria assim: GROUP_CONCAT(institution SEPARATOR ','), vou editar minha resposta. @MiguelSilva

Comment: Vou testar, uma dúvida, no tratamento dos dados usando Ireport é possível substituir as virgulas por uma quebra de linha?

Comment: Aí já não vou saber te responder, porém se você souber o que ele espera para quebrar linha, você pode colocar no separator do group_concat e testar por exemplo GROUP_CONCAT(institution SEPARATOR '\r\n'), algo assim. Abs